# Difference between list assignment

Tags: python

Help me understand difference between list assignment.

I have found that assignment like this

```
a[0] = b[0]
b[0] = a[0]
```

Is different from

```
a[0], b[0] = b[0], a[0]
```

The values of a and b in both the cases are different , however both of these assignment methods does the same , swapping.

You can run my sample code to see this

```
    a = [0,1,2]
    b = [3,4,5]
    print "Value of a and b before swaping :"
    print "value of a :" , a
    print "value of b :" , b
    print "\nswap in two line"
    a[0] = b[0]
    b[0] = a[0]
    print "value of a :" , a
    print "value of b :" , b
    print "\nswap in one line"
    # Reinitilizing value of a and b before performing swaping
    a = [0,1,2]
    b = [3,4,5]
    a[0], b[0] = b[0], a[0]
    print "value of a :" , a
    print "value of b :" , b
```

How are two methods of assignment different? At the first glance they look the same and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> however both of these assignment methods does the same [thing], swapping.

Not quite... The former example *doesn't* swap.  Instead, it takes the first element of `b` and puts it in the first element of `a`.  Then it takes the first element of `a` (which used to be the first element in `b`) and puts it back into b -- leaving `a[0]` and `b[0]` with the same value.

When it's all on the same line, python actually does something a little magical.  It effectively creates a new tuple `(b[0], a[0])` and then uses that tuple to assign things back into `b` and `a`.  In other words, it behaves effectively the same as:

```
temp = (b[0], a[0])
a[0] = temp[0]
b[0] = temp[1]
```

notice how this is logically different from the first case you had.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the order in which assignment takes place. It has nothing to do with lists however.

The code

```
 a = b
 b = a
```

First assigns `b` to `a`, then assigns `a` to `b` resulting in both having the value that `b` had before.

On the other side

```
a, b = b, a
```

first evaluates `b, a`. And then take those values and assign to `a` and `b`. This results in a proper swap.